# An unexpected error has occurred with Stripe.js

Tags: stripe-payments

I have been receiving this error with stripe

```
An unexpected error has occurred with Stripe.js. This may be due to network connectivity issues, so you should try again (you won't be charged twice). If you're still having problems, please let us know!
```

The form never submits when card is invalid but
the form submits successfully after showing this error and in stripe dashboard the card and customer is added with no problem.

Comment: Just ran into this same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: check whether the form is submitting twice or stripe token already present

Answer (score 1):

Like surendar said himself: check whether the form is submitting twice.

I had hijacked the submit event of my form via Javascript and forgot to return "false" in order to prevent the default submit action. After I fixed this (i.e. returned "false" in my submit method), it all worked fine.

Comment: This was a large issue I was fighting against for two days. Though it was an Angular JS and stripe problem